# shorten down if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I am working on a school project and have made this code:

```
$("#pakke1, #pakke2, #pakke3, #pakke4, #pakke5, #pakke6, #pakke7, #pakke8, #pakke9, #pakke10, #pakke11, #pakke12").click(function() {
    if($(this).is('#pakke1')){
        $("#modal1").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke2")){
        $("#modal2").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke3")){
        $("#modal3").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke4")){
        $("#modal4").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke5")){
        $("#modal5").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke6")){
        $("#modal6").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke7")){
        $("#modal7").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke8")){
        $("#modal8").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke9")){
        $("#modal9").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke10")){
        $("#modal10").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke11")){
        $("#modal11").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
    else if($(this).is("#pakke12")){
        $("#modal12").css("display","inline-block");  
    }
});
```

and I am having a hard time shortening it down so it can connect the #pakke id to the right #modal id when clicked.
The more simple the better, I have very limited knowledge of working with arrays.
hope someone can help me as my deadline is closing in.

Comment: show your html code also .

Comment: @shubham715 while many questions do leave out html where it's required to answer the question, this is not one of them.  showing the html would have no benefit to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick for you since you want to "match" pakke1 with modal1 and so on.

So we take the `id` with `.attr("id")` and remove "pakke" so we are left with the number.

Then you can add the number to `$("#modal")` like this `$("#modal" + number)`

```js
$("[id^='pakke']").click(function() {
  var number = $(this).attr("id").replace("pakke", "");
  $("#modal" + number).css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

Comment: @KennetN No problem, happy to help

Comment: You can even shorten it to `$("[id^='pakke']")`

Comment: @Rajesh You are correct, not sure why I didn't do it this time, normally I do it this way :)

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different approach, you can use regex to just extract the number from the string.

```
var number = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^\D+/g, '');
$("#modal" + number).css("display", "inline-block");
```

Tip: using `replace` instead of `match` as in case id does not have a number, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery start with selector where you can bind click event for all elements starting id with `pakke`, see below code

```
$("[id^=pakke").click(function() {//bind click handler for all having id start with pakke
  var number = $(this).attr("id").replace("pakke", "");
  $("#modal" + number).show();//use show() method instead of display 
});
```

This will help you if there is increase or decrease in number of elements having id start with `pakke`